# not able to configure php with apache

Tags: php, apache

I have downloaded `httpd-2.2.25-win32-x86-openssl-0.9.8y.msi` and `php-5.5.10-Win32-VC11-x86.zip`. After configuring `httpd.conf` and `php.ini` when i am trying to restart the apache

using

> httpd.exe -k restart

i am getting following error and i dont know how to resolve it , its related to some compatibility stuff but no idea how to get rid off it

> C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Fo
>   undation/Apache2.2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/Apache So ftware Foundation/Apache2.2/php/php5apache2_4.dll into
>   server: The specified pro cedure could not be found.

here is the loadmodule

> LoadModule php5_module "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Apache2.2\php\php5apache2_4.dll"

and .dll file is exist over this path

Comment: does the dll file exist at the path in the error message?

Comment: check `php5apache2_4.dll` is present or not in php installation folder

Comment: yeah its exist , i have checked the path